# Extremely high CPU usage in Django

Tags: performance, python, django, debugging

I am helping to develop a fairly complex web application with Django.  However some pages are taking 10+ seconds to render.  I can't seem to get to the bottom of why this is so slow.  The Django Debug Toolbar shows that the bottleneck is clearly CPU, rather than the database or anything else, but it doesn't go into any further detail (as far as I can see).  I have tried running a profiler on the system, but can't make head or tail of what is going on from this either.  It only shows deep internals as taking up the vast majority of the time, especially `<method 'poll' of 'select.poll' objects>`, and other such functions as `builtins.hasattr`, `getmodule`, `ismodule`, etc.

I've also tried stepping through the code manually, or pausing execution at random points to try to catch what's going on.  I can see that it takes quite a long time to get through a ton of import statements, but then it spends a huge amount of time inside render() functions, taking especially long loading a large number of model fields--something in the order of 100 fields.

None of what is happening looks wrong to me, except for the insane amount of time everything takes to run.  It's as though Python is just taking forever to load and parse each .py file before doing any processing.  However, this is all running on a brand new Digital Ocean server with an SSD, with Gunicorn, PostgreSQL and Nginx.  Does anyone have any hints how I can get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Please execute `vmstat -n 1 60` on your DO system while you're accessing the Django page and then add the result into your question.

Comment: @user1 That didn't show anything out of the ordinary at all I'm afraid.  After spending a ton of effort debugging this further, it seems that the issue might only be because the models we are using are so complex that there are thousands (not hundreds) of fields, and therefore field template renders. So it's looking like there is no easy way around this.

Comment: In the end, we just implemented page caching to speed this up.

Comment: Well...yeah ^^ thx for the feedback